# aginity workbench for redshift temp table auto-complete

Tags: autocomplete, aginity

I'm a newbie to Redshift, I'm using Aginity workbench for Redhsift. Pretty familiar with MS SQL server though. My question is about auto-complete, when I write a regular query like this below, as soon as I type in "m.", a list of all fields in "mytable" show up.

```
select t.
from #temp_table t;
```

However, if I write something like this below, when I type in "t.", it only pops up a list with a single "*" asterisk entry, it doesn't show me a list of fields in "#temp_table" like the previous example.

```
select m.
into #temp_table
from mytable m;

select t.
from #temp_table t;
```

On MS SQL, intellisense shows up fields name just fine for temp tables.

I'm using:

Aginity Workbench for Redshift
Version 4.8.0.2551 (build 6/14/2016)
Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 (64-bit)

Please advise.

Thank you!

Comment: This question is not about Amazon Redshift. The question is about the Aginity Workbench. The auto-complete is a functionality of the workbench and it is unrelated to the underlying database

Comment: Update: I wrote to the Aginity folks directly, their response is pasted below:

Thanks for your interest in our products. You are correct, the auto-complete feature does not work with temporary tables. These tables are not stored in the pg_catalog where this function gets the metadata to display on the screen.

Comment: Thank you for contributing back to the community and posting the answer for all of us. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: For anyone else who lands here wondering how to refresh the autocomplete cache in Aginity (which is how I ended up here), for non-temporary tables you can right-click on a table name and "refresh fields". For all I know, there may be other better methods ...

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer provided by Aginity:

> Update: I wrote to the Aginity folks directly, their response is
>   pasted below: Thanks for your interest in our products. You are
>   correct, the auto-complete feature does not work with temporary
>   tables. These tables are not stored in the pg_catalog where this
>   function gets the metadata to display on the screen